# How can I make the logo a link to the home page?

Tags: magento2

I cant find the option to make it possible to click on my site's logo and direct myself to the homepage.

Comment: Welcome to Magento SE @dylan. Please explain a bit more so that people can understand what do you want and help you.

Answer (score 1):

In `app/design/frontend/VENDOR/THEME/Magento_Theme/templates/html/header/logo.phtml`, you can add the link to:

```
<a class="logo" href="<?php echo $this->getUrl(''); ?>" title="logo title"><img src="your logo image path" /></a>
```

OR Like this

```
<a
    class="logo"
    href="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getUrl('')) ?>"
    title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($storeName) ?>"
    aria-label="store logo">
    <img src="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getLogoSrc()) ?>"
         title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getLogoAlt()) ?>"
         alt="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getLogoAlt()) ?>"
            <?= $block->getLogoWidth() ? 'width="' . $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getLogoWidth()) . '"' : '' ?>
            <?= $block->getLogoHeight() ? 'height="' . $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getLogoHeight()) . '"' : '' ?>
    />
</a>
```

Comment: I do not have that file path. Was it deprecated?

Comment: If not found this file then enabled frontend path debug mode from admin then check from where to come this logo then update code accordingly...